# What does this message mean and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot? "... You are in emergency mode. ..."

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my PC before (an SSD + an HDD), and recently a power failure damaged my SSD, and I alternated the SSD and re-installed the system with / and /boot in the SSD and /var, /home, and swap in the HDD.

It worked for about a week. But today I cannot boot the system and get messages like in the photo. (I tried many times and the messages are similar.)

Could you tell me what this message means and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot?

(By the way, I suspect the HDD has some problem, or the power line to support the HDD has some problem.)

[image: The photo of the message]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seem to be two main causes of emergency mode in my experience

1. `fstab` problems

   - You changed a partition and didn't change `fstab` properly to reflect it, or you made some other kind of error in `fstab`.
   - Since you report that you messed about with partitions, I would suspect this.

If `fstab` is ok, check for...

2. Partition corruption problems:

   1. Boot to live USB
   2. do an `lsblk` in the terminal
   3. then `sudo su`, and `fsck -f /dev/sdxx` all the partitions

Comment: My fstab is consistent with blkid. My system boot after option 2. (Many FS errors found and corrected). Thank you a lot!