# How to fix Ubuntu getting stuck into Emergency Mode

Tags: boot, live-usb, bootloader

I have a home server running Ubuntu Desktop 23.04, which had auto power restored on and I have experienced frequent power cuts. Since then, my server boot into Ubuntu Emergency Mode. I've tried several troubleshooting methods without any luck. I will list all the methods I've tried till now.

**Method 1:** This method has worked for me every time I've experienced an emergency mode. which is to run fsck manually. However, this time I get a "disk is mounted" error.

**Method 2:** I tried to get to the bottom of this by trying to find the root cause of the problem. Here's what it says when I try to run `journalctl -xb | grep failed`

I am not sure how to recover things from here. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get to resolve this issue. I am wondering if using live boot disk can help this in any way possible.

Comment: It is impossible to add images without the URLs to the images.  Add them as links into the comments or edit the links into your post.  The URLs don't exist in the post, so we can't embed images we don't know about.

Comment: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1470673/243321 Part 2 works around the "disk is mounted" error.