# Boot fails with: Failed to start userspace out-of-memory killer

Tags: boot, 22.04

I recently had an update of the kernel (usual apt update/upgrade). Since then, the system won't startup.

Message: "Failed to start userspace out-of-memory killer"

What can I do to resolve the error?

[image]

Comment: There's...quite a bit more failed than that one thing. The key fact is that your system ended up in *emergency mode*. So see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1470673/243321