# Ubuntu does not boot - fails at "recovering journal"

Tags: boot, 22.04

The system uses Ubuntu 22.04.

The problem started after I installed and used many new packages. The system froze and I hard rebooted the system.

On the next boot-up attempt, it stopped after:

1. "recovering journal"
2. "Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/...", the partition is the swap.
3. "Dependency failed" for swap partition.
4. Timed out for /boot/efi
   ...

[image: Screenshot]

I tried booting in recovery. It blocked at the same place.

I booted-in with a thumb-drive. I tried `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3`, which is the install partition. It did not fix the problem.

I used Boot-Repair without any success. That process re-does the fstab file also.

What else can I try?

Update:

I ran `fsck -f /dev/sdxx` on all the partitions. It did not fix the problem. I ran Boot-Repair which I thought would fix the fstab file, but the system still did not boot. I then ran the fsck commands again just to try, without success.

The fstab file did not change before or after the operations. The partition UUIDs in the fstab file matches the UUIDs from the `blkid`.

Comment: There is a problem with `fstab`. You must have modified it, or your partitions.

Comment: duplicate of [What does this message mean and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot? "... You are in emergency mode. ..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470669/what-does-this-message-mean-and-what-to-do-to-let-my-ubuntu-boot-you-are-i)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I updated the question. I ran fsck on all the partitions and I ran Boot-Repair. It affected the fstab file. I don't know if it was the expected result or if any of the operations made things worse.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I haven't recently changed the drives physically, or changed the partitions. I did not change the fstab file myself.

Comment: Your fstab file just reinforces the errors you already posted. It shows the partitions that the system is trying to mount and failing (swap and efi). You can use `sudo blkid` to show the partitions that actually exist on your system.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I updated to post. The UUIDs from blkid seem to correspond to the UUIDs in the fstab file.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm out of ideas.