# Emergency Mode: Unable to logging in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, error-handling

I am in an emergency mode and tried with multiple commands to logging in into Ubuntu but unfortunately couldn't able to succeed to resolve the issue. I'm new to Ubuntu, what can I do to fix this (or find a deeper error to look into)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this message mean and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot? "... You are in emergency mode. ..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470669/what-does-this-message-mean-and-what-to-do-to-let-my-ubuntu-boot-you-are-i)