# Linux boots into emergency mode Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, filesystem, fstab

When I look at the `journalctl`, I see these two error messages related to time out waiting for the device:
[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

Here is a look at my `fstb` :

[image: fstab]

Not sure what to do.

Comment: I would install ubuntu fresh again. are you dual with windows?  if yes, install windows fresh again, then ubuntu.

Comment: Posting screenshots instead of text makes it very difficult to look into your issue. Did you change something recently? See https://askubuntu.com/a/1470673/243321 reinstall is not required

Comment: Looks like the parition you made for `/boot` is not being mounted (and `/boot/efi` cannot be mounted either as it needs `/boot` to be mounted before it). are you able to run `lsblk -l -o name,uuid` on the rescue shell? if so please add the output above.